# The bootstrap-vue <b-modal> does not appear

Tags: bootstrap-vue

I need to create a modal that pop-ups when the button is clicked; i tried with bootstrap-vue, following the documentation but it didn't worked.

I put  in my vue project but it doesn't work. The button is there, but when i click the modal doesn't appear. When i go to the console, it says that the directive  is not recognized. I will put the code and the error below

```
<template>
...
 <c-card>
 <div>
      <b-button v-b-modal.exclude class="center" size="lg" variant="danger">Excluir conta</b-button>
       <b-modal id="exclude" title="bootstrapVue">
        <p class="my-4">Are you sure that you want to exclude your account?</p>
      </b-modal>
  </div>


    </c-card>

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex'
import cCard from '@/components/Card'
import pStatusAchievements from './_partials/StatusAchievements'
import pStatusApps from './_partials/StatusApps'
import pStatusNetwork from './_partials/StatusNetwork'
import pStatus from './_partials/Status'
import pStatusPublication from './_partials/StatusPublication'
import pMyAccount from './MyAccount'
import pPowerUp from './_partials/PowerUp'
import {BModal, VBModal} from 'bootstrap-vue'
const cContentHeader = () => import('@/components/ContentMiddleHeader')

export default {
  name: 'Perfil',

  components: {
    cContentHeader,
    cCard,
    pStatusPublication,
    pStatusNetwork,
    pStatusApps,
    pMyAccount,
    pStatusAchievements,
    pStatus,
    pPowerUp,
    BModal,
  },

  data () {
    return {
      pubStatus: 1200,
      networkApps: [
        { name: 'network', title: 'rede' },
        { name: 'appsUsage', title: 'uso dos apps' }
      ]

    }
  },

  directives: {
    'b-modal': VBModal
  },
```

That is the vue-warn

```
[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <b-modal> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option.

found in

---> <Perfil> at src/views/perfil/Perfil.vue
       <MFeed> at src/views/mobile/mFeed.vue
         <SlideXLeftTransition>
           <NavbarContent> at src/views/mobile/mContent.vue
             <NavbarContent> at src/layouts/main/MainLayout.vue
               <FadeTransition>
                 <App> at src/App.vue
                   <Root
```

Comment: `v-b-modal.excluir` doesn't match the id on the `b-modal`, and where do you import `b-button`?

Comment: sorry, i edited the code ´<b-modal>´ to put the name in english and forgot to edit in ´v-b-modal.excluir´ but in the original code, both the id and the v-b-modal are "excluir"

Comment: b-buttons are imported globally on the project